# Why does insert script with Bookshelf.js hang?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am a bit confused why the Node.js script does not exit:

```
// myscript.js
var Model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'models'
});
var m = Model.forge({name: 'hello'});
m.save();
console.log("End");
```

But when running this with `node myscript` the script does not exit.

- What is preventing the script from exiting?
- How to cleanly exit after the model is saved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is preventing the script from exiting?

Knex holds a pool of connections to your database. Although your script's execution ends, behind the scenes Knex is still maintaining these, preventing the program from closing.

> How to cleanly exit after the model is saved?

You can tear down all the database connections by calling `knex.destroy()`. You must do this *after* your queries are complete.

```
// myscript.js
var Model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'models'
});

Model.forge({name: 'hello'}).save().then(function(model) {

  console.log('model has been saved', model);

}).catch(function(error) {

  // it's bad practise to omit some sort of error reporting.
  console.error('something went wrong!');

}).finally(function() {

  // tear down connection.
  return bookshelf.knex.destroy();

}).then(function () {

  // This is the actual 'end' of the program.
  console.log("End");

});
```

Comment: it works, but referencing knex via bookshelf might be worth to mention:  return bookshelf.knex.destroy();